# ms word, create table of contents on side of the document that keeps following you

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink, table-of-contents

i wanted to ask...
in ms word, is there something you can create on the side of a document that stays on the screen even as you scroll down the page? i wanted to create a table of contents on the side where i can jumping back and forth throughout the document.

basically...something that contains the overview on the side. i have a lot of bullet points and lots of sub-bullet points. i wanted to be able to see the top of the hierarchy easily wherever i am on the document and be able to jump around easily.

thank you

Comment: A Word doc is not a web page with floating menus! I doubt this can be achieved, even with VBA, but perhaps someone will prove me wrong. Maybe Word's `View tab / Navigation Pane` is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I open a document in which I have used "styles" for headings, I automatically get a table of contents listing in a pane on the left titled "Navigation".  That is in MicroSoft Office 2010.

I am sure you can look for instructions on applying heading styles somewhere on this site or out there.

Once you have done that, to get the view (which does stay put when you scroll through the document):

tab called "**View**"  >  little area of the ribbon called "**Show**"  >  checkbox called "**Navigation**"

Note that within the Navigation window there are 3 little tabs.  You want the left one.

Comment: ...glad to help!  I just posted a question to a StackExchange site (actually Stack Overflow) for the first time tonight, and then I thought I should hunt down a question I could answer.  ...payback for all the learning I've done so far on these sites just by searching.  Here's hoping someone's quick on my question.  lol

Comment: It worked for me in Office 2013